# css and Jquery show hide sticky submenu

Tags: jquery, hover, hide, show

I have a navigation with a horizontal sub-nav that needs to be a sticky on child pages.

I have all of that working with CSS, but the issue is that I need the sticky `ul` on the child pages to be hidden when I hover over another parent `li` and go back to sticky when I am not hovering. I think jQuery is the only solution for this.

Here is what I have so far:

```
<style type="text/css">
.current-menu-parent ul{
display:block !important;
position:absolute!important;
}
#primary-nav ul li:hover ul {
display:inline;
position:absolute;
}
#primary-nav ul li > ul{
    display:none;
}
</style

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"type="text/javascript">    </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#primary-nav ul li").mouseover(function(){
  $('.current-menu-parent ul').hide();
});
 $("#primary-nav ul li").mouseout(function(){
  $(".current-menu-parent ul").show();
});
});
</script>
<body>
<div id="primary-nav">
  <ul>
    <li>item</li>
    <li class="current-menu-parent>This is the current menu parent item
        <ul>
            <li>Current page</li>
            <li>page</li>
            <li>page</li>
        </ul>
     </li>
   <ul>
</div>
```

Sorry if there are typo's just re-wrote this quickly.

Here is the link so you can see the problem firsthand. Just try clicking on a sub-page to see the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `important` on `.current-menu-parent ul`

```
.current-menu-parent ul{
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
}
```

which is causing to stick.

Next issue is causing due to `.show()` on `.mouseout()` and viceversa.

```
$("#primary-nav ul li").mouseover(function(){
    $('.current-menu-parent ul').show();
});
$("#primary-nav ul li").mouseout(function(){
    $(".current-menu-parent ul").hide();
});​
```

Refer **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/MkqWL/1/)**

Comment: well that solved the first problem... Pretty close now. The only issue is that now when I hover over an li in the sticky ul it flips out like the jquery is getting inherited to those items. I tried targeting the parent li much more specifically and using the first child selector but neither seemed to work.